# MacBook keeps crashing every day: Panic (element modified after free)

Tags: crash, kernel-panic

My MacBook 16" keeps crashing, mostly when connected to external screen and provides the crash report below.

Unfortunately I can not visit the next Apple store as it's closed and perhaps somebody here can give me some hints.

MacBook 16", 2,4 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9, 32Gb, 2667 MHz DDR4, AMD Radeon Pro 5500M 8 GB.

```
panic(cpu 14 caller 0xffffff800a89f6b6): [kext.kalloc.2048]: element modified after free (off:1584, val:0x0000210100000000, sz:2048, ptr:0xffffff937ebc8000, prot:zero)
 1584: 0x0000210100000000
 1592: 0x0000000b00005400
 1600: 0x0000000000000009
 1608: 0x0000060300000100
 1616: 0x0000015400000154
 1624: 0x0000001000000a00
 1632: 0x000008340000041a
 1640: 0x0000000000001400
 1672: 0xfffffffe00000000
Backtrace (CPU 14), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffa13276b080 : 0xffffff800a08e02d 
0xffffffa13276b0d0 : 0xffffff800a1d48e3 
0xffffffa13276b110 : 0xffffff800a1c4eda 
0xffffffa13276b160 : 0xffffff800a032a2f 
0xffffffa13276b180 : 0xffffff800a08d84d 
0xffffffa13276b2a0 : 0xffffff800a08db43 
0xffffffa13276b310 : 0xffffff800a89d68a 
0xffffffa13276b380 : 0xffffff800a89f6b6 
0xffffffa13276b800 : 0xffffff800a0ec816 
0xffffffa13276b870 : 0xffffff800a09d60c 
0xffffffa13276b8c0 : 0xffffff800a7af582 
0xffffffa13276b8e0 : 0xffffff7f98bb8089 
0xffffffa13276b920 : 0xffffff7fa3523b6c 
0xffffffa13276b960 : 0xffffff7f98bbaeec 
0xffffffa13276b990 : 0xffffff7fa352409d 
0xffffffa13276b9c0 : 0xffffff7fa3533109 
0xffffffa13276ba00 : 0xffffff7fa35213d2 
0xffffffa13276ba80 : 0xffffff800a820dc0 
0xffffffa13276bad0 : 0xffffff800a81f037 
0xffffffa13276bb20 : 0xffffff800a82911b 
0xffffffa13276bc80 : 0xffffff800a180401 
0xffffffa13276bd90 : 0xffffff800a0936ad 
0xffffffa13276be00 : 0xffffff800a069c85 
0xffffffa13276be60 : 0xffffff800a0812a2 
0xffffffa13276bef0 : 0xffffff800a1a91fd 
0xffffffa13276bfa0 : 0xffffff800a033216 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(442.9)[5523A2B9-D179-3560-9738-E720033965D7]@0xffffff7fa351a000->0xffffff7fa3584fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[9B4B41D7-B68F-33D5-80A4-2C4C4A649F6D]@0xffffff800b6b8000->0xffffff800b6cdfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(585.1)[CC341A35-707F-3C8B-8EFD-925F742166A1]@0xffffff7fa369b000->0xffffff7fa36c9fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[B99B3B05-71B8-3178-8C27-E0A0ACA9F16E]@0xffffff800cb5f000->0xffffff800cb87fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(47)[3F7604AB-EA65-3904-A1F4-AFEB25D288A7]@0xffffff800cb96000->0xffffff800cb98fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(290.7)[6AE0FD31-9444-350A-88A6-620DF634FF78]@0xffffff800cc89000->0xffffff800cca5fff
         com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX6000(4.0.4)[F9A8D4D1-CA26-3CD7-B8B5-0D9C0AF929A1]@0xffffff7f98b7d000->0xffffff7f98cb1fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(442.9)[5523A2B9-D179-3560-9738-E720033965D7]@0xffffff7fa351a000->0xffffff7fa3584fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(585.1)[CC341A35-707F-3C8B-8EFD-925F742166A1]@0xffffff7fa369b000->0xffffff7fa36c9fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[B99B3B05-71B8-3178-8C27-E0A0ACA9F16E]@0xffffff800cb5f000->0xffffff800cb87fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(290.7)[6AE0FD31-9444-350A-88A6-620DF634FF78]@0xffffff800cc89000->0xffffff800cca5fff

Process name corresponding to current thread: firefox
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
20E241

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 20.4.0: Thu Apr 22 21:46:47 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.101.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 068F99A3-1DB3-31C0-87D5-09942F122BB6
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000009e00000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff800a000000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000009e10000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff800a010000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8009f00000
System model name: MacBookPro16,1 (Mac-E1008331FDC96864)
System shutdown begun: NO
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 59084557528634
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x000035bcb210311d
  Sleep   : 0x0000236fad608896 0x0000bb543377ea4c 0x0000236d06af6e61
  Wake    : 0x0000236fe03261ae 0x0000bb7d62348296 0x0000236fbf5d560d
last started kext at 38999089138715: >usb.cdc.acm   5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7fa330e000, size 8192)
last stopped kext at 39130256195303: >usb.serial    6.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7fa3378000, size 20480)
loaded kexts:
>AudioAUUC  1.70
@filesystems.afpfs  11.3
@nke.asp_tcp    8.2
>AGPM   122
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    4040.11
>!AHIDALSService    1
@fileutil   20.036.15
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000    4.0.4
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>BridgeAudioCommunication   140.4
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   4.0.4
>AGDCBacklightControl   6.2.9
>!AMuxControl2  6.2.9
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 6.2.9
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   6.2.9
>pmtelemetry    1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>usb.!UUserHCI  1
|IO!BSerialManager  8.0.4d18
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!AHV   1
>!ADiskImages2  1
>!A!IKBLGraphics    16.0.2
>!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.433
>!ABridgeAudio!C    140.4
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 16.0.2
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>usb.realtek8153patcher 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostBillboardDevice  1.0
>BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   556.100.11
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIeMac   1
@filesystems.apfs   1677.100.114
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    311
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
>!UAudio    405.39
$SecureRemotePassword   1.0
@kext.triggers  1.0
>!AHIDKeyboard  224
>!AHS!BDriver   4040.11
>IO!BHIDDriver  8.0.4d18
>!AActuatorDriver   4440.3
>!AMultitouchDriver 4440.3
>!AInputDeviceSupport   4400.35
@kext.AMDRadeonX6100HWLibs  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000HWServices  4.0.4
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
>!AGraphicsControl  6.2.9
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000Framebuffer 4.0.4
@kext.AMDSupport    4.0.4
|IOAVB!F    940.4
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    980.4
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
@!AGPUWrangler  6.2.9
|IONDRVSupport  585.1
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    8.0.4d18
|IO!BHost!CTransport    8.0.4d18
|IOAudio!F  300.6.1
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
|IOAccelerator!F2   442.9
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    6.2.9
|IOGraphics!F   585.1
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  8.1.4
>!AThunderboltPCIUpAdapter  4.1.1
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.1.4
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.1.4
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  290.7
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!ABCMWLANCoreMac   1.0.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IO80211!FV2    1200.12.2b1
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
>corecapture    1.0.4
>!AXsanScheme   3
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.8
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.2
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$!AImage4   3.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   980.4
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 8.0.4d18
|IOReport!F 47
|IO!BPacketLogger   8.0.4d18
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  511.101.1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  184.101.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  436.100.4
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  436.100.4
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 11.1
@kec.Libm   1
```

The problem does not seem to be bundled to Firefox, which I was using in this case. This is another crash report:

```
panic(cpu 5 caller 0xffffff800d49f6b6): [kext.kalloc.2048]: element modified after free (off:1584, val:0x0000210100000000, sz:2048, ptr:0xffffff937f8f2800, prot:zero)
 1584: 0x0000210100000000
 1592: 0x0000000b00005400
 1600: 0x0000000000000009
 1608: 0x0000060300000100
 1616: 0x0000015400000154
 1624: 0x0000001000000a00
 1632: 0x000008340000041a
 1640: 0x0000000000001400
 1672: 0xfffffffe00000000
Backtrace (CPU 5), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffa13a303080 : 0xffffff800cc8e02d 
0xffffffa13a3030d0 : 0xffffff800cdd48e3 
0xffffffa13a303110 : 0xffffff800cdc4eda 
0xffffffa13a303160 : 0xffffff800cc32a2f 
0xffffffa13a303180 : 0xffffff800cc8d84d 
0xffffffa13a3032a0 : 0xffffff800cc8db43 
0xffffffa13a303310 : 0xffffff800d49d68a 
0xffffffa13a303380 : 0xffffff800d49f6b6 
0xffffffa13a303800 : 0xffffff800ccec816 
0xffffffa13a303870 : 0xffffff800cc9d60c 
0xffffffa13a3038c0 : 0xffffff800d3af582 
0xffffffa13a3038e0 : 0xffffff7f9b7b8089 
0xffffffa13a303920 : 0xffffff7fa6123b6c 
0xffffffa13a303960 : 0xffffff7f9b7baeec 
0xffffffa13a303990 : 0xffffff7fa612409d 
0xffffffa13a3039c0 : 0xffffff7fa6133109 
0xffffffa13a303a00 : 0xffffff7fa61213d2 
0xffffffa13a303a80 : 0xffffff800d420dc0 
0xffffffa13a303ad0 : 0xffffff800d41f037 
0xffffffa13a303b20 : 0xffffff800d42911b 
0xffffffa13a303c80 : 0xffffff800cd80401 
0xffffffa13a303d90 : 0xffffff800cc936ad 
0xffffffa13a303e00 : 0xffffff800cc69c85 
0xffffffa13a303e60 : 0xffffff800cc812a2 
0xffffffa13a303ef0 : 0xffffff800cda91fd 
0xffffffa13a303fa0 : 0xffffff800cc33216 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(442.9)[5523A2B9-D179-3560-9738-E720033965D7]@0xffffff7fa611a000->0xffffff7fa6184fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[9B4B41D7-B68F-33D5-80A4-2C4C4A649F6D]@0xffffff800e2b8000->0xffffff800e2cdfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(585.1)[CC341A35-707F-3C8B-8EFD-925F742166A1]@0xffffff7fa629b000->0xffffff7fa62c9fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[B99B3B05-71B8-3178-8C27-E0A0ACA9F16E]@0xffffff800f75f000->0xffffff800f787fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(47)[3F7604AB-EA65-3904-A1F4-AFEB25D288A7]@0xffffff800f796000->0xffffff800f798fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(290.7)[6AE0FD31-9444-350A-88A6-620DF634FF78]@0xffffff800f889000->0xffffff800f8a5fff
         com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX6000(4.0.4)[F9A8D4D1-CA26-3CD7-B8B5-0D9C0AF929A1]@0xffffff7f9b77d000->0xffffff7f9b8b1fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(442.9)[5523A2B9-D179-3560-9738-E720033965D7]@0xffffff7fa611a000->0xffffff7fa6184fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(585.1)[CC341A35-707F-3C8B-8EFD-925F742166A1]@0xffffff7fa629b000->0xffffff7fa62c9fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[B99B3B05-71B8-3178-8C27-E0A0ACA9F16E]@0xffffff800f75f000->0xffffff800f787fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(290.7)[6AE0FD31-9444-350A-88A6-620DF634FF78]@0xffffff800f889000->0xffffff800f8a5fff

Process name corresponding to current thread: phpstorm
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
20E241

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 20.4.0: Thu Apr 22 21:46:47 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.101.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 068F99A3-1DB3-31C0-87D5-09942F122BB6
KernelCache slide: 0x000000000ca00000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff800cc00000
Kernel slide:      0x000000000ca10000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff800cc10000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800cb00000
System model name: MacBookPro16,1 (Mac-E1008331FDC96864)
System shutdown begun: NO
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 15062593186611
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x00000db308842e53
  Sleep   : 0x00000da962863332 0x00008592138f2264 0x00000d9d503e0acb
  Wake    : 0x00000da9950ec765 0x000085b0a2f6d544 0x00000da974498fa4
last started kext at 14976225634489: >AudioAUUC 1.70 (addr 0xffffff7fa5f8c000, size 12288)
last stopped kext at 14384364419252: >!UAudio   405.39 (addr 0xffffff7fa5f12000, size 315392)
loaded kexts:
>AudioAUUC  1.70
@filesystems.afpfs  11.3
@nke.asp_tcp    8.2
>AGPM   122
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    4040.11
>!AHIDALSService    1
@fileutil   20.036.15
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000    4.0.4
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   4.0.4
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 6.2.9
>BridgeAudioCommunication   140.4
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>!A!IKBLGraphics    16.0.2
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   6.2.9
>pmtelemetry    1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>usb.!UUserHCI  1
>!ABridgeAudio!C    140.4
>AGDCBacklightControl   6.2.9
|IO!BSerialManager  8.0.4d18
>!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!AHV   1
>!ADiskImages2  1
>!AMuxControl2  6.2.9
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.433
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 16.0.2
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>usb.!UHostBillboardDevice  1.0
>usb.realtek8153patcher 5.0.0
>BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   556.100.11
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIeMac   1
@filesystems.apfs   1677.100.114
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    311
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
>usb.cdc.acm    5.0.0
>usb.serial 6.0.0
>!UAudio    405.39
$SecureRemotePassword   1.0
@kext.triggers  1.0
>!AHIDKeyboard  224
>!AActuatorDriver   4440.3
>!AMultitouchDriver 4440.3
>!AInputDeviceSupport   4400.35
>!AHS!BDriver   4040.11
>IO!BHIDDriver  8.0.4d18
@kext.AMDRadeonX6100HWLibs  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000HWServices  4.0.4
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    8.0.4d18
|IO!BHost!CTransport    8.0.4d18
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000Framebuffer 4.0.4
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IOAVB!F    940.4
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    980.4
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
@kext.AMDSupport    4.0.4
@!AGPUWrangler  6.2.9
>!AGraphicsControl  6.2.9
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
|IONDRVSupport  585.1
|IOAudio!F  300.6.1
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOAccelerator!F2   442.9
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    6.2.9
|IOGraphics!F   585.1
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  8.1.4
>!AThunderboltPCIUpAdapter  4.1.1
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.1.4
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.1.4
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  290.7
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!ABCMWLANCoreMac   1.0.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IO80211!FV2    1200.12.2b1
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
>corecapture    1.0.4
>!AXsanScheme   3
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.8
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.2
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$!AImage4   3.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   980.4
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 8.0.4d18
|IOReport!F 47
|IO!BPacketLogger   8.0.4d18
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  511.101.1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  184.101.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  436.100.4
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  436.100.4
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 11.1
@kec.Libm   1
```

Comment: Judging from the last kext, do you have an Audio device connected? Or any other peripherals?

Comment: Yes, it's a HP thunderbolt dock.

Comment: It could be a hardware incompatibility with the HP Dock. Which model in particular? Over this past summer I was testing a Dell Thunderbolt dock, which was Windows-only, and although some of the functionality didn't seem to be affected by using a Mac, some of the capabilities just weren't available because it needed Windows drivers. I suspect the HP Dock is designed for Windows only. I looked just now at all the specs I could find about the various HP docks, and none of them are macOS compatible.

Comment: It's HP Thunderbolt Dockingstation with Audio, 120W G2

According to the docs it should be compatible...

Comment: I got `element modified after free` for the first time today. Previously all kind of other kernel panics every other day. Same device...

Comment: The answer about the Radeon driver below may be correct. I don't believe this is dock specific because I'm hitting this exact same problem with a Kensington dock. The forum thread below also mentions CalDigit and Belkin docks.

Answer (score 7):

Its bug in GPU Radeon driver :( Apple cant fix it from macos 11.3. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/678644 Downgrade to 11.2.3 is workaround, but not recommended: this macOS has zero day vunerabilities https://techcrunch.com/2021/05/24/malware-xcsset-macos/ . Wait fix from apple.